# Удаление дочернего елемента WPF Viewport3D

Tags: c#, wpf

Здравствуйте.
В Viewport3D добавляю линию, линия рисуется без проблем, методом из библиотеки 
3DTools

```
ScreenSpaceLines3D lin = new ScreenSpaceLines3D();
Point3D p = new Point3D(1, 2, 3);
Color c1 = Colors.Red;
lin.Color = c1;
lin.Points.Add(p);
p.X = 0;
p.Y = 0;
p.Z = 0;
lin.Points.Add(p);
mainViewPort.Children.Add(lin);
```

Как можно эту же линию удалить ?
xxx.Children.Remove удаляет с коллекции после чего вызывает ошибку "Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта."

Comment: выложи проект..

Comment: @codename0082016 pastebin.com/BXPnCFam сs pastebin.com/GEnHa13R xaml

Comment: @codename0082016 https://yadi.sk/d/sZox9hWe3GwXSn сам проект

Comment: Я не знаю в чём проблема. Ошибка возникает после любой попытке использовать `mainViewPort.Children` после удаления любого элемента.

Comment: @codename0082016 Это реально пофиксить ?

Comment: А опубликуйте stack trace ошибки, плиз. У меня есть подозрение, что ошибка в другом месте.

Comment: @VladD Не совсем понимаю как это сделать. Выше я прикрепил ссылку на сам проект, может это поможет.

Comment: @Fionor: Ну, когда у вас происходит исключение, в Visual Studio открывается Exception Assistant или как там его. Там можно посмотреть объект исключения. В нём есть поле `StackTrace`, в котором то, что нужно, в текстовом виде.